# Is there an equivelant of pythons struct.unpack in vb.net

Tags: python, vb.net, binary

I'm trying to convert the following piece of python code to vb.net:

```
struct.unpack('>L', self.header[0xf4:0xf8])
```

From searching it seems that there is no obvious one-on-one equivalent to this in vb.net but I was wondering if there was another way to achieve the same results as the code above without the use of any third party libraries if possible.

I'm still trying to find a way to do this in vb.net, however after some searching I've managed to break the above down into its component parts as follows:

'>L' - In python this means an unsigned long with big endian byte order
header is a variable that contains the first 78 bytes of the binary file I am trying to parse.
oxf4 and oxf8 are just the range of indexes I want to unpack.

Its the '>L' part that is causing me the most problems since trying to convert the sequence of bytes to a long unsigned or otherwise is still not giving me the correct result.

Comment: A little googling suggests you want to declare an `IntPtr` that points to `self.header[0xf4]` (probably using `AddressOf`) and then you extract the `int` that it points at (probably using `Marshal.ReadInt`). Not a VB.NET programmer in 5 years, but that should get you close.

Comment: @hughdbrown Thank you for getting me started i'll take a look at that now.

Comment: Check this link http://forums.asp.net/t/909857.aspx?convert+struct+to+byte+array , I think it helpful.